# Updating table Fields Using EF Database First usind EDMX

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I came across a very strange scenario, I have this Model (Customer) inside my EDMX file

```
public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string FaxNo { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Modified { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PMFormID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> InspectionFormID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RepairFormID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Now when I tried to update this `

```
Customer customerToUpdate = _context.Customers.Where(c => c.ID == customer.ID).SingleOrDefault(); 
        customerToUpdate.CompanyName = customer.CompanyName;
        customerToUpdate.CustomerNo = customer.CustomerNo;
        customerToUpdate.PhoneNo = customer.PhoneNo;
        customerToUpdate.FaxNo = customer.FaxNo;
        customerToUpdate.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        customerToUpdate.InspectionFormID = customer.InspectionFormID;
        customerToUpdate.PMFormID = customer.PMFormID;
        customerToUpdate.RepairFormID = customer.RepairFormID;
        customerToUpdate.Email = customer.Email;
        context.SaveChanges();
```

All the fields are been updated except of the Modified field. Tha value of it is still null. What is wrong? please help

Comment: What's the column type of `modified` (per the database)?

Comment: The column type is DateTime, I did this the same with my other entity and it work but its so frustrating that in this entity it doesn't work. Maybe there are issues that I never knew. Im using EF Database first approach using EDMX (drag and drop one).

Comment: Is it Nullable in database?

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table; something that may be conflicting?

Comment: Atish: yes its nullable

Comment: Brad: I have no triggers, stored procedure or any functions that may cause conflict.

Comment: Your EDMX? Are you using Code First or Database First?

Answer (score 0):

Really strange. Try it this way:

```
customer.Modified = DateTime.Now;

// This should find Customer by EntityKey and apply all fields to context entry
// so you shouldn't assign each property value
_context.Customers.ApplyCurrentValues(customer);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Or may be it is better to implement `Modified` field behavior at the database level as a SQL UPDATE trigger?